# NativeScript Permissions - Cannot find name 'android'?

Tags: nativescript

I'm using the [`Spartadigital NativeScript Permissions`](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@spartadigital%2Fnativescript-permissions) plugin

I've also  did :

```
tns plugin add @spartadigital/nativescript-permissions
```

And inside the `ts` file  :

```
import {Permissions} from '@spartadigital/nativescript-permissions';
```

However when I run `tns run android` : I get :

> node_modules/@spartadigital/nativescript-permissions/permissions.android.d.ts(2,37):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'android'.
>
> node_modules/@spartadigital/nativescript-permissions/permissions.android.d.ts(3,34):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'android'.
>   node_modules/@spartadigital/nativescript-permissions/permissions.ios.d.ts(24,47):
>   error TS2552: Cannot find name 'NSObject'. Did you mean 'Object'?
>   node_modules/@spartadigital/nativescript-permissions/permissions.ios.d.ts(24,67):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'.
>   node_modules/@spartadigital/nativescript-permissions/permissions.ios.d.ts(26,20):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'.

Looking at the file , I see that it doesn't know `android` :

[image]

Nor other IOS objects :

[image]

I already have tns-platform-declarations :

[image]

**Question:**

Why doesn't it recognize those keywords and how can I fix it ?

[package.json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c8f3d543d1cd61af2435348e2f8dd659)

[ts.config](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/76162a841b0103a38c23f408a41c9801)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the `tns-platform-declarations` module to your project, this will give you the typings for the native namespaces, classes, etc and enable intellisense also for what is provided by this module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations

Comment: I already have it : https://i.imgur.com/Eeqxvmk.jpg - maybe that's the reason ? -------->  : https://i.imgur.com/73M3jli.jpg

Comment: Ahh, read the question too quick :) so you have the `references.d.ts` file? Also, is this happening in your local project or only in the plugin itself. I don't use the platform-declarations a lot myself but when I do have it on a project it seems to resolve correctly. I just don't recall if it will resolve down into a dependency bc the path. Might be some other config option to make that work or add the platform-declarations to the dependency so it can resolve to the `references.d.ts` some how

Comment: [What can I say , you're the man. I **copied** those declarations to the root `reference.d.ts` and it works.](https://i.imgur.com/yr9fXWB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

an easy answer would be to add `declare var android` to the top of the typescript file (under imports) you are calling it in. NativeScript knows where to get android from once its compiled.